# AndroidのBLE送受信間隔

Tags: android, bluetooth

Andorid 5.0以降ではBLEの送受信間隔を
SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY　や　ADVERTISE_MODE_LOW_LATENCY　などの値で
設定するのが普通だと思うのですが、
これをタイマなどを利用し、任意の間隔に設定する方法は無いでしょうか？

同様に送信出力についてもADVERTISE_TX_POWER_HIGH などを使わず
直接数値で設定する方法についても知りたいです。

Answer (score 1):

出来ません。connection intervalなどのリンクレイアの値は、BLEチップのファームウェア(FW)で設定されています。FWのコードは、オープンソースではなく、バイナルで提供されています。AOSPからビルドし直しても、変更することは出来ません。

SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCYは、セントラルが接続前のスキャンを休止なしで行うモードです。接続後は関係ありません。